# Abort Firestore read if slow / no connection

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to give Firestore query (read) a set amount of time to complete, and if not done by this time, aborts the read request and carries on with other code?

App starts with a Firestore query checking Firestore document time stamp which is used to see if an update is needed. Works fine. However if no signal connection the app stalls at this point awaiting a response from Firestore. Which never happens if no signal, so not useable offline.

Looking at giving this query a chance, but then moving on if not returned in set time.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using proper `async await` methods you can `task?.cancel()` after a set amount of time

Comment: If not using async?

Comment: Then the solution has to be much more specific. Start with why is "it" waiting in the first place?

Comment: No network connection

Comment: Your looking at it to superficially, if the response isn’t valuable/critical why are you coding it to wait instead of react to a valid value? Also ask yourself about offline contingencies, are they necessary or available?

Comment: It’s important if there is a network connection as used to determine if update needed. But if no network then not needed as even if there was an update possible, it wouldn’t happen as no network to download update. So checking if there is an update is important, and something that I want to do. But if there happens to be no network, then not critical to app use

Comment: Sounds like you have a roadmap.